# Modeling time series of sinusoid with inclining amplitude plus white noise

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to approach modeling time series data. I have made a synthetic dataset that is the sum of a sinusoid whose amplitude increase with time plus white noise. I'm considering each timestep as hourly so the sequence has a period of 12 hours.

1. What would be the procedure if I wanted to fit as SARIMA model for this (assuming no knowledge of the underlying function that generated it)? Or is some other model class better suited?
2. How should I approach this if the noise exhibits heteroskedasticity (say increasing variance with time)?

Code

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss, adfuller

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

result = []
for i in range(500,5000):
    result.append(np.sin(np.pi/6 *(i -6)) * i /1000 + np.random.normal(scale=1))
result = np.array(result)
```

[image]

The p-values for the kpss and adfuller test outputs

```
print(kpss(result )[1])
print(adfuller(result)[1])

0.036179219434385186
1.1328771447754276e-25
```

The autocorrelatoin and partial autocorrelation plots are below:

[image][image]

Comment: If you know the model form (like in your simulated data), you should usually seek to fit that form of model, not a different one; I would not start by thinking SARIMA for these data.

Comment: I would like to pretend that I do not know the underlying process that generated the data (i.e. if I was just given the points and not the equation)

Comment: If you're taking the position that it's legitimate to look at the data in order to choose a model to be fitted to the same data (with all the implications that would have for inference or prediction), with sufficient data (and low enough noise relative to the signal) you can usually see that SARIMA would be unsuitable.

Comment: What would be a good model choice for this series? Is there a reason why SARIMA is a bad choice here?

Comment: SARIMA can't reproduce the behavior of the series. You need a model that will reflect that increasing amplitude of the seasonal term.